# Universal Windows App: Two buttons inside of ListViewItem

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, listviewitem

I have two buttons inside the DataTemplate of my Listview.ItemTemplate.

I have no problem accessing each one on their own using a Click event, however, when I click one of the buttons I want to change the foreground color of the *other* button. How do I get the instance of the other button (that wasn't clicked) in the ListViewItem?

Comment: Please provide the codes you have tried so far.

Comment: Loaded event for each button, and store it in a private field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to change the foreground color of the other button when you click one of the two buttons, you don't have to get the instance of the other button. Using [Behaviors SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) may be a better choice in this scenario.

Following is the xaml code I have verified:

```
<Page
x:Class="ListViewWithTwoButtonDemo.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ListViewWithTwoButtonDemo"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<ListView Header="Medications" x:Name="myList" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="400">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="medName" Text="{Binding Path=MedName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="whatFor" Text="{Binding Path=WhatFor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <!--Use Behaviors SDK here, and no code behind is needed -->
                <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btn1" Content="Button 1">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=btn1}">
                            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=btn2}" PropertyName="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                        </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
                <!--Use Behaviors SDK here, and no code behind is needed -->
                <Button Grid.Column="3" x:Name="btn2" Content="Button 2">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=btn2}">
                            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=btn1}" PropertyName="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                        </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Page>
```

Following is the output:
[image]

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help.